# Displaying Directory Structure in CheckedListBox C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My ultimate goal is to allow a user to select what directories they want as a checkbox type thing. Can I display a drill down directory structure with checkboxes next to each folder using this control or should I got a different route?

Edit: More Information.

I have a Windows Form application in Visual Studio using c#.
It is to allow myself and some select friends automatically backup folders to amazon s3 on a daily basis.
I need to figure out how to display a computers directory structure which you can drill down into and check a box next to any folder you want.
That way the app will only backup folders you choose.
A CheckBoxList seems like the right way to go but I can't figure out how to make it a drilldown list. It seems to only display a list of items. What is another control I could try or another method I could explore?

Comment: Not enough information in the question, and the question is too ambiguous - "Can I x or should I y". Yes, you can x. Should you do y? Dunno. Not enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need to show a hierarchy just use a TreeView with checkboxes.

you are not telling if you are in Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.NET, MVC etc... still there should be such "checkboxable" TreeView in all these platforms.

Answer (score 0):

A `CheckedListBox` displays a flat structure. A `TreeView` would be more appropriate to present a nested directory structure.